# mysql foregin key error 150

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

i am trying to create an order management system 
but after creating base tables ie (`Suppliers,Customers,Categories,Employees,Shippers`)
i go to next level with creating product and orders, i am able to add foregin keys in those table.
now i added last level table `oderDetail` and trying to add foregin key to OrderID and ProdcuID but it just gives me error 150
mysqldump

```
-- MySQL Administrator dump 1.4
--
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   5.5.8


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;


--
-- Create schema testdrive
--

CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS testdrive;
USE testdrive;

--
-- Definition of table `categories`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `categories`;
CREATE TABLE `categories` (
  `CategoryID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Description` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `Picture` blob,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CategoryID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `categories`
--

/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `categories` DISABLE KEYS */;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `categories` ENABLE KEYS */;


--
-- Definition of table `customers`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `customers`;
CREATE TABLE `customers` (
  `CustomerID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `CompanyName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `ContactName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `ContactTitle` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `Address` text NOT NULL,
  `City` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `Region` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `PostalCode` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `Country` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `Phone` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `Fax` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CustomerID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `customers`
--

/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `customers` DISABLE KEYS */;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `customers` ENABLE KEYS */;


--
-- Definition of table `employees`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `employees`;
CREATE TABLE `employees` (
  `EmployeeID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `LastName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `FirstName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `Title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `BirthDate` date NOT NULL,
  `HireDate` date NOT NULL,
  `Address` text NOT NULL,
  `City` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `Region` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `PostalCode` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `Country` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `HomePhone` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `Extension` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Photo` blob NOT NULL,
  `Notes` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`EmployeeID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `employees`
--

/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `employees` DISABLE KEYS */;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `employees` ENABLE KEYS */;


--
-- Definition of table `orderdetail`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `orderdetail`;
CREATE TABLE `orderdetail` (
  `OrderDetailID` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `ProductID` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `OrderID` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `Quantity` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `Discount` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`OrderDetailID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `orderdetail`
--

/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `orderdetail` DISABLE KEYS */;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `orderdetail` ENABLE KEYS */;


--
-- Definition of table `ordres`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `ordres`;
CREATE TABLE `ordres` (
  `OrderID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `CustomerID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `EmployeeID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `OderDate` date NOT NULL,
  `RequiredDate` date NOT NULL,
  `ShippedDate` date NOT NULL,
  `ShipperID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`OrderID`),
  KEY `Order_Customer` (`CustomerID`),
  KEY `Order_Employee` (`EmployeeID`),
  KEY `Order_Shipper` (`ShipperID`),
  CONSTRAINT `Order_Customer` FOREIGN KEY (`CustomerID`) REFERENCES `customers` (`CustomerID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `Order_Employee` FOREIGN KEY (`EmployeeID`) REFERENCES `employees` (`EmployeeID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `Order_Shipper` FOREIGN KEY (`ShipperID`) REFERENCES `shippers` (`ShipperID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `ordres`
--

/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `ordres` DISABLE KEYS */;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `ordres` ENABLE KEYS */;


--
-- Definition of table `products`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `products`;
CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `ProductID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ProductName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `SupplierID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `CategoryID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `QuantityPerUnit` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `UnitPrice` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ProductID`),
  KEY `Product_Supplier` (`SupplierID`),
  KEY `Product_Category` (`CategoryID`),
  CONSTRAINT `Product_Supplier` FOREIGN KEY (`SupplierID`) REFERENCES `suppliers` (`SupplierID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `Product_Category` FOREIGN KEY (`CategoryID`) REFERENCES `categories` (`CategoryID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `products`
--

/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `products` DISABLE KEYS */;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `products` ENABLE KEYS */;


--
-- Definition of table `shippers`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `shippers`;
CREATE TABLE `shippers` (
  `ShipperID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `CompanyName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `Phone` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ShipperID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `shippers`
--

/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `shippers` DISABLE KEYS */;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `shippers` ENABLE KEYS */;


--
-- Definition of table `suppliers`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `suppliers`;
CREATE TABLE `suppliers` (
  `SupplierID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `CompanyName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `ContractTittle` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `Address` text NOT NULL,
  `City` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `Region` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `PostalCode` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `Country` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `Phone` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `Fax` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `HomePage` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`SupplierID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `suppliers`
--

/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `suppliers` DISABLE KEYS */;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `suppliers` ENABLE KEYS */;
```

and here is what i am trying to do

```
  ALTER TABLE testdrive.orderdetail
 ADD CONSTRAINT orderDetail_Product FOREIGN KEY (ProductID) REFERENCES testdrive.products (ProductID) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
 ADD CONSTRAINT OrderDetail_Order FOREIGN KEY (OrderID) REFERENCES testdrive.ordres (OrderID) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

forein key between two fields that are not exactly the same. The fields type, dimension and flags should be identical.

add    `unsigned`   int in the column  `( productId, orderId )`    of  table   `testdrive.orderdetail`